# NVidia Quadro FX and NVS in one workstation

Tags: graphics, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

is it possible to use at the same time Quadro FX and NVS in the same Windows 7 workstation?

Comment: We're there two cards in particular you were looking at? It might depend on the card. Also motherboard may help a bit.

Comment: I have Quadro NVS 450 which serves 4 large screens, however it's OpenGL is very slow, I need a faster OGL for 1 application so would like to set up an additional card

Comment: As long as your PSU can handle it you should be fine.

Comment: what about driver compatibility? can FX & NVS use the same one?